# Open video in default media player in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to open a video in my default media player. I have inserted video hyperlinks in my HTML document.

When I click on the hyperlink, instead of opening the video, it downloads the video.

I want the hyperlink to open the video in the user's default media player without downloading the video.

This is what I have so far:

```
<a href="file://F:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv">Example tutorial video</a>
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can use video tag in html5:

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<p>
Video courtesy of 
<a href="https://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.
</p>

</body> 
</html>
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: So basically it is impossible to click on the link and open the default media player?

For example how IE asks if you wanna open the video

Comment: Yeah as far as I know, you can not open default media player by just clicking on link.

Answer (score 0):

That's simply not how you embed video in html5. This is:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't open the default media player without downloading, but if you want you can make a page with just a html5 video player like Mayers said.

Comment: I understand. Thank you